# GORM v2 migration questions

Tags: migration, go-gorm

We're upgrading from GORM v1 to v2 and I'm trying to understand the proper way to change the migrations (also using gormigrate v2). Before we had something like this:

```
transaction.Model(&Table1{}).ModifyColumn("title", "VARCHAR(200)")
transaction.Model(&Table2{}).AddForeignKey("table1_id", "table1s (id)", "CASCADE", "CASCADE")
```

Should we use `Migrator().CreateConstraint()` and `Migrator().AlterColumn()` now instead? If so, I don't understand the syntax since the doc is very vague. For instance, to make `AlterColumn` work, we have to set gorm tags on the models beforehand and GORM will know what to change automatically? And if so, can I also use the gorm tags for constraints instead? Thanks